I cannot load trained model in Google Colab TPU - error caused by batch_shape
I am using notebooks in Kaggle and Google Colab. After I trained my model in Kaggle (GPU P100) and tried to load it in Colab (TPU) I received this error:
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'InputLayer' using config={'batch_shape': [None, 191], 'dtype': 'float32', 'sparse': False, 'name': 'input_layer'}.

Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments: ['batch_shape']

I had been loading models in Colab T4 GPU (and also CPU) before and this was working perfectly fine. Does anybody know what I need to do to port the existing model to Colab TPU?
I was trying to find out what versions of keras are used in each env, so I ran this:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

print(tf.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)

In Kaggle GPU P100 and Colab CPU this results in:
2.15.0
3.4.1

While in Google Colab TPU with the above code tensorflow version shows 2.15.0 and the keras part returns an error:
AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute '__version__'
Side note:
I am not sure why Colab currently prevents me from using GPU. I have not exceeded limits as I have not trained with GPU for the last 3 days. And from my experience both GPU and TPU share the same limit so I am surprised TPU works (well... it activates at least) and GPU does not.
Either way, can anybody help with the porting of models to TPU?

I have just experienced the same behavior using the CPU version of Colab. The models that I was loading previously without any problem are now crashing with the exception: Unrecognized keyword arguments: ['batch_shape'].
I hope that Google will resolve the issue soon but I am stuck for now. So I will appreciate if somebody can tell me if how I can circumvent this problem.

The error arises due to mismatch between the versions.TensorFlow==2.15 overwrites keras with an older version(keras==2.15). If you install TensorFlow 2.15, you should reinstall keras 3 afterwards. This step is not necessary for TensorFlow versions 2.16 onwards, it will install Keras 3 by default. So to fix this issue issue, you can either upgrade your TensorFlow version or manually install keras==3.0 after installing TensorFlow 2.15 and import keras directly instead of using from tensorflow import keras. kindly refer to this document. And also refer this gist.
